# Can changing reference frames generate entanglement in identical particles?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement

Suppose we have a pair of qubits, physically realised as two spin-half particles in some separable pure state $|\psi\rangle$, separated by a distance '$l$', large enough to be regarded as distinguishable particles in some reference frame $\mathsf{S}$.

Let $\mathsf{S'}$ be another reference frame moving with some velocity(relativistic) '$v$'. From $\mathsf{S'}$ the separation between the two qubits is Lorentz contracted to $$l' = l \sqrt{\left(1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)}$$.

My question is:

1. At what value of $l'$ do the particles become indistinguishable, if at all?
2. If the particles become indistinguishable at some point, the joint state has to be entangled from symmetry considerations. Where does this entanglement come from?

PS: I tried to make sense of the indistinguishability by thinking of De Broglie wavelengths but couldn't completely wrap my head around it

Comment: If I remember correctly, a Lorentz boost will shrink the orbital wavefunction, so no matter how fast you go the electrons would still be very localized (distinguishable).

Comment: What if the particles are outside the atoms? Theoretically, we can have two entangled electrons that are outside any atom. Since electrons are regarded as point particles, what should be the correct procedure to ascribe a notion of length to them?

Comment: I was not considering bounded electrons. Imagine that in your rest frame each electron has a spherical probability distribution such that they can be found with 90% probability inside a radius r. Then I would imagine that as you do a Lorentz boost, each probability sphere shrinks in the direction of the boost. But I still have to find a good source, so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I get what you are saying, I myself tried to think along that line as well. What I couldn't get around is what's stopping me from deciding the extent of the sphere at  99% or at 67%. What is the exact criterion for two particles to be in/distinguishable?

Comment: I asked this in Physics SE which might be of help: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/671091/do-wavefunctions-shrink-under-lorentz-boosts